# Restrict a user from viewing other user's processes

Tags: bash, shell, process, ps, top

Suppose there are two users : **user1** & **user2**.

Now we know that if I give `top -u user1`, I can see only the process respective to `user1`.

But if I do `top -u user2`, I can see all the process running under `user2`.

Similar is the case with `ps -f -U user1`.

Is there a way to make `ps` & `top` restrict to only see the processes running under their Id & not others ?

Comment: View this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux  and in the in the .bash_profile file create a alias for ps and top to view only there specific process; Thus even if they run top or ps; It will show only process specific to them

Comment: an alias is easily shipped around - he would have to face a rather low-level threat then.